# Appium Maven Project unable to run to real device

Tags: java, maven, testing, testng, appium

i was writing scriptss on appium as an eclipse maven project.While trying to run the script using TESTNg to a connected mobile device.. getting the following error

*The version  used are:
Wnindows 8.1
JDK  9.0.4
JRE  9.0.4
Appium :1.4.16
Java Client:5.0.4
Eclipse :OXygen*

```
        org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -version"
The system cannot find the path specified.
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.13 seconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'CEREBTECH', ip: '192.168.57.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:83)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:93)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:72)
    at lotzaTesting.LotzaBase.createAppiumDriver(LotzaBase.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Please help with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue once. this issue happens due to the hidden files for environment path setup on windows. Enable your windows file systems hidden files to display then Environment Variable can visible. Follow the mentioned resource link to enable/display the hidden files then retry issue will be resolved.

https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=27479

Comment: Stiil facing the same issue.my appium log is https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-maven-project-unable-to-run-to-real-device/21335/4

Comment: Then try to remove the appium settings and Unlock app from your device, these two default apps will be installed for the first time appium script run on real device and do adb kill-server and adb start-server then up and run the appium server to launch your script. Hope this time your issue will be resolved! if no, share your script and with whole logs.

Comment: The steps i tried are Step1:adb uninstall io.appium.settings, Step3:adb uninstall io.appium.unlock Step 3.adb Kill-server ,Step 4:adb start-server............ Stll getting the same error